# Destroying CListBox after LBN_KILLFOCUS leads to Exception

Tags: mfc

My goal is to destroy a CListBox-Object after it loses focus. I added the following code to the parent object:

```
BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CChildView, CWnd)
    ON_LBN_KILLFOCUS(IDC_LISTBOX, OnLBKillFocus)
END_MESSAGE_MAP()

void CChildView::OnLBKillFocus()
{
    listBox->DestroyWindow();
}
```

I created the object like this:

```
listBox = new CListBox;
listBox->Create(WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD, CRect(10, 110, 100, 200), this, 1112);
```

But after the `OnLBKillFocus` function executed I get an exception in `DefWindowProc`. Apparently the already destroyed ListBox trys to process a `WM_KILLFOCUS` message and crashes, because the window handle is `NULL`.

Here is part of the stack trace:

```
mfc110ud.dll!CWnd::DefWindowProcW(unsigned int nMsg, unsigned int wParam, long lParam) Line 1141    C++
mfc110ud.dll!CWnd::WindowProc(unsigned int message, unsigned int wParam, long lParam) Line 2138 C++
mfc110ud.dll!AfxCallWndProc(CWnd * pWnd, HWND__ * hWnd, unsigned int nMsg, unsigned int wParam, long lParam) Line 290   C++
mfc110ud.dll!AfxWndProc(HWND__ * hWnd, unsigned int nMsg, unsigned int wParam, long lParam) Line 453    C++
mfc110ud.dll!AfxWndProcBase(HWND__ * hWnd, unsigned int nMsg, unsigned int   wParam, long lParam) Line 304  C++
user32.dll!_InternalCallWinProc@20()   Unknown
...
```

Does anybody have an idea what is the cause of this crash and how it can be avoided?

Comment: Seems like a timing issue of the sequence of messages as they are processed.  Have you tried **posting** a WM_DESTROY to the listbox from the handler of the kill focus?

Comment: I tried `PostMessage(WM_DESTROY)`. That did not have any effect. (No crash but the window stayed). But it seems to work if I do `PostMessage(WM_CLOSE)`. Is that the expected behaviour?

Comment: @rrirower: It is not allowed to post WM_DESTROY yourself. The only correct way to destroy a window is the use of the DestroyWindow function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Decouple the action that should cause the destruction and destruction itself.

After you receive the WM_KILLFOCUS event, just use PostMessage with a private message (registered window message or WM_APP+n) and upon receive of this message destroy the window.

Comment: Is there any reason not to use `PostMessage(WM_CLOSE)`? Sofar it seems to work. Are there any downsides?

Comment: I am not sure what you consider to be a 'normal child control'. But the listbox in question disappears. Of course I am not sure what happens behind the curtains and if this leads to other problems later on.

Comment: I suppose that the defin window proc just calls DestroyWindow upon receipt of WM_CLOSE. So this is you solution.

Comment: @sietschie: [WM_CLOSE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632617.aspx): *"By default, the [**DefWindowProc**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633572.aspx) function calls the [**DestroyWindow**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632682.aspx) function to destroy the window."*